# Erro de compilação -lpthread

Tags: c, c++

Estou tentando compilar um arquivo .c, mas sempre que chamo o gcc nomedoarquivo.c, tenho o seguinte erro:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

O arquivo não está com nenhum erro de sintaxe, nem nada do tipo.

Qual pode ser o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o compilador MinGW32 o qual utiliza a API do Windows (que não possui referência a Posix Thread, vulga pthread).

Para solucionar seu problema de compilação você deve instalar [PThreads para Windows](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) o que fará com que as mesmas fiquem a disposição tanto no Windows como no compilador MinGW.

Ainda se o caminho da instalação for diferente do caminho de libs do MinGW você deverá referenciar através do comando -L"Caminho/Para/A/Lib/pthread" nos parâmetros do linker (ld).

Resposta baseada na pergunta "[Cannot find -lpthread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827392/cannot-find-lpthread)" do StackOverflow em Inglês.